# How do Hash-functions encode an infinite amount of data into a finite amount?

Tags: hash, information-theory

Hash-functions always create an output with a fixed length, even though the input can be infinitely large.

So how is it possible, that no information is lost here? Shouldn't some inputs result in the same output then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Two inputs can result in the same output, resulting in a hash collision.

Hashes are designed so that hashing text is very easy, but reversing the process is difficult. The point of hashing isn't to store information. Instead, hashes are commonly used in security (and also data structures).

For instance, websites will hash a user's passwords and store the hashes instead of the physical passwords. This way, if the website's security is breached, the attacker can only obtain the hashes, which still doesn't let the attacker log in, as it is very difficult to reverse-engineer the password.

The hash set is another application of hashing. By hashing an object and storing only the hashes, you can check whether an object is present or not present in the set in constant time. You only have to search through all of the objects in the hash set that have the same hash as the object that you are checking. As the size of the hash set grows, so does the chance of a hash collision.

Comment: So you could in fact use two or more passwords for a login, if the password check is performed with hash keys?

Comment: Yes but the chance of two hashes matching exactly for a good hash algorithm is almost zero

Answer (score 1):

> So how is it possible, that no information is lost here?

It's not possible, and lots of information is lost.

In the case of a perfect hash there is no collision and we could even argue that information isn't really lost (it's just not contained in the system alone) because we know all possible inputs and know there is no collisions in the hashes produced, but they can be used as an index in a way that isn't possible or as good with the input data, so they are useful.

In the case of a hash-based collection we use a hash code to (hopefully) have few collisions so we get close to O(1) lookup, but have some means to handle it if a collision does happen.

In the case of a cryptographic hash we could have collisions but it's extremely hard to deliberately do so, for similar (roughly speaking) reasons as to why its hard to break modern cryptography, so while you could have two passwords with the same hash you couldn't find it easily (especially if you aren't going to e.g. have a password of several thousand pages of text).

In the case of a checksum hash we could have collisions, but that they're unlikely means that if we have corruption we probably won't have the matching hash.